# four square venues in side custom shapes on google maps in ios swift

Tags: swift, google-maps, foursquare

How to get foursquare venues in side a shape drawn on google maps. Search api of foursqaure doesn't provide any straight forward method.

Answer (score 1):

With the [venue/search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) API on Foursquare you can pass `ne` and `sw` parameters to define a bounding box to search within.

For complex polygons, you can pass a `polygon` parameter to the [venues/explore](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) endpoint.

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?client_secret=****&client_id=****&polygon=37.80463017025873%2C-122.42786407470703%3B37.802595683318046%2C-122.42374420166016%3B37.798662182986945%2C-122.42219924926756%3B37.79676317682161%2C-122.43009567260741%3B37.79255806087506%2C-122.43919372558592%3B37.79255806087506%2C-122.44314193725585%3B37.79513541839677%2C-122.44588851928712%3B37.803273851858656%2C-122.44709014892577%3B37.80286695148153%2C-122.44279861450195%3B37.805850835522065%2C-122.43370056152344%3B37.80463017025873%2C-122.42786407470703&query=dinner&v=20161101
```

Comment: by ne and sw we can only get venues inside a rectangle, and there is no polygon parameter for fourSquare API.

Comment: @ShithinPV I updated my answer with an example using the "polygon" parameter with venues/explore API